# How to create the following script in Google SpreadSheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to create the following script in Google SpreadSheets:
When entering a word into a certain cell, it is necessary to make the script enter the last name or first name into the cell 8 cells to the right. For example, in cell A1 someone enters the word "apple" and in cell A9 "the surname Smith should be displayed"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy to do in a spreadsheet cell but it's very easy to do in a html textbox.  So I would do it in a dialog or sidebar using the oninput event to look for suggestions in your suggestion list that start with those letters and perhaps event wait until you get a few letters into it.  So you need to start thinking about where the suggestion are going to come from and how you going to filter the list to come up with the appropriate suggestions.

Here's some code from an old project prior to ES6:

Code.gs:

```
function getSuggestions(s){
  
  if(s){
    var vA=[];
    var cA=getAllContacts();
    for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++){
      if(cA[i].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(s.toLowerCase())>-1){
        vA.push([cA[i][0]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return vA;
}
```

javascript:

```
function getSuggestions(){
    var txt=$('#rec').val();
    if(txt.length>0){
      $('#rec').css('background','yellow');
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
        $('#rec').css('background','white');
        //updateSelectList(vA);
        updateDiv(vA);
      })
      .getSuggestions(txt)
    }else{
      updateSelectList([]);
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<div id="content"><h1 id="hdg1">Final Report</h1>
    <label for="selPid">PID</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="selPid" placeholder="Selected PID" size="10" readonly /><br />
    <div id="emaildialog">
      Recipient Search:<br />
      <input id="rec" type="text" oninput="getSuggestions();" placeholder="Enter Search String slowly. Yellow=accessing server" size="50" /><br />
      Suggestions:<br />
      <div id="sugdiv" style="width:100%;background-color:#ffffff;"></div>
      Recipients:<br />
      <textarea id="recipients" cols="50" rows="4" placeholder="Sent to first recipient. Remaining recipients are blind copied."></textarea><br />
      Message:<br />
      <textarea id="msg" cols="50" rows="4" placeholder="Enter message to send with the attachments." >This is a copy of our apps Final Report.</textarea><br>
      <input type="button" id="send" value="Create PDF and Send Email" onClick="createAndSendReport();" />
    </div>
    <div id="dynamic"></div>
  </div>
```