# Auto complete for Google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm developing an addon for Google docs, when users type a specific token e.g: **{{**, a list of suggestions will display to users and filter the list as users type more characters. The list of suggestions is a fixed set and contains under 100 terms. I'm digging through [google apps script documentatio](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/overview)n and [Github samples](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples) but couldn't find anything.
It is very similar to the [universal @ menu](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/10/easily-add-to-google-docs-with-new.html) feature:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve what I want, not neccessary a Google Docs add-on. Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178179/7215091

Comment: Hi there @BobT.! Please read Cooper's answer and see if it fits your project. If it doesn't, please edit your question to show your project so far and point where you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

After further digging around and going through the related post which @Cooper suggested. I came to the conclusion there is no way to achieve what I want. There is no trigger available for onChange event for Google Docs.